# Trying to save Outlook MailItem as an HTML formatted MSG but it opens as plain text

Tags: c#, outlook, format, interop

I have a c# class file that references Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library.

It creates an Outlook MailItem, formats as HTML and saves the MSG file locally.  The problem is that when I open the saved file, Outlook treats it as plaintext.  Here is an example of what I'm looking at:

```
oMsg = oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
oMsg.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
oMsg.HTMLBody = @"<b>Test</b>";
...
oMsg.SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, filename), Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
```

When I open the saved file Test is not bold and the format shown for the message is listed Plain Text.  Is there something I'm missing?

I should add also that when I send this message to my Outlook inbox (rather than save) it works.  I'm not sure what is wrong with the MSG file.

Comment: Do you call oMsg.Save before calling SaveAs?

Comment: I just tried and the same behavior occurred.  The text is unformatted, and under "Format Text" tab Plain Text is selected. I see though that Save()  placed a correct HTML copy in my Draft folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had no problem with the following test script (I used Outlook Spy to run it):

```
set oMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
oMsg.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
oMsg.HTMLBody = "<b>Test</b>"
oMsg.Save
oMsg.SaveAs "c:\temp\testhtml.msg", olMSG
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I at least know the code is fine.  Something is screwy on my end.

Comment: It runs but still gives me the behavior described in my question.  The resulting MSG file saved locally is plain text but the file in my Drafts folder is HTML.  I have no clue why it behaves this way but I can find a workaround given it's in the Drafts folder.  Thanks!

Comment: If you have OutlookSpy installed, try to open the MSG file (click OpenIMsgOnIStg) and check if PR_RTF_COMPRESSED contains the RTF-wrapped HTML.